# Solr MoreLikeThis does not return any results

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Any help will be appreciated.

Using solr 8.2

I created a core using

```
./solr create -c playground
```

imported example docs using

```
 curl 'http://localhost:32576/solr/playground/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/home/vagrant/books.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

the data is the sample data coming with solr

I did not change anything else in the configuration

trying to add **mlt=true&mlt.fl=name** to my query did not yield any result

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/playground/select?mlt.fl=name&mlt=true&q=*%3A*
```

I always get

```
"moreLikeThis":{
    "0553573403":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    }}
```

in the end of my results

this is the full result

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "mlt":"true",
      "mlt.fl":"name",
      "_":"1577018250160"}},
  "response":{"numFound":10,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"0553573403",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["A Game of Thrones"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692236529664},
      {
        "id":"0553579908",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["A Clash of Kings"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":2,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692242821120},
      {
        "id":"055357342X",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["A Storm of Swords"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
        "series_t":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
        "sequence_i":3,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692243869696},
      {
        "id":"0553293354",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Foundation"],
        "price":[7.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["Isaac Asimov"],
        "series_t":"Foundation Novels",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"scifi",
        "_version_":1653437692244918272},
      {
        "id":"0812521390",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["The Black Company"],
        "price":[6.99],
        "inStock":[false],
        "author":["Glen Cook"],
        "series_t":"The Chronicles of The Black Company",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692244918273},
      {
        "id":"0812550706",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Ender's Game"],
        "price":[6.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["Orson Scott Card"],
        "series_t":"Ender",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"scifi",
        "_version_":1653437692245966848},
      {
        "id":"0441385532",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Jhereg"],
        "price":[7.95],
        "inStock":[false],
        "author":["Steven Brust"],
        "series_t":"Vlad Taltos",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692245966849},
      {
        "id":"0380014300",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["Nine Princes In Amber"],
        "price":[6.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["Roger Zelazny"],
        "series_t":"the Chronicles of Amber",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692247015424},
      {
        "id":"0805080481",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["The Book of Three"],
        "price":[5.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["Lloyd Alexander"],
        "series_t":"The Chronicles of Prydain",
        "sequence_i":1,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692248064000},
      {
        "id":"080508049X",
        "cat":["book"],
        "name":["The Black Cauldron"],
        "price":[5.99],
        "inStock":[true],
        "author":["Lloyd Alexander"],
        "series_t":"The Chronicles of Prydain",
        "sequence_i":2,
        "genre_s":"fantasy",
        "_version_":1653437692248064001}]
  },
  "moreLikeThis":{
    "0553573403":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0553579908":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "055357342X":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0553293354":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0812521390":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0812550706":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0441385532":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0380014300":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "0805080481":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    },
    "080508049X":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
    }}}
```

Added the definition of the name field in  general_schema.xml

```
 <field name="name" type="text_general"/>
```

Comment: Please try with mt.fl=field_name&mlt.match.include=false&mlt=true. It looks like your fields are multlivalued=true and needs to have different fieldtype for the field.

Comment: Add the text_general type as fieldType to your field name...

Comment: Thank you  @Abhijit Bashetti I tried both with the same results.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I am having the same problem

Comment: Sorry to say that I moved to elastic search